# How to call stored procedure contains dynamic SQL with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm using Entity Framework get data from SQL Server. I have a stored procedure that contains dynamic SQL to search data.

My SQL code looks like this:

```
create procedure SearchProduct
    (@ProductId int = null,
     @ProductName nvarchar(50) = null,
     @ProductCatId int = null)
as
    Set NoCount ON
    declare @SqlStr nvarchar(max)
    declare @ParamList nvarchar(2000)
begin
    set @SqlStr = 'select p.ProductId, p.ProductName, p.ProductCatName, p.From, p.To from Product p where (1=1)'
-- p.from , p. to is warranty period

    if @ProductName is not null
       set @SqlStr = 'and p.ProductName like ''%' +@ProductName + '%'' )'
    ......
    set @ParamList ='@ProductId,@ProductName,@ProductCat'

    execute sp_executesql @sqlStr, @ParamList, @ProductId, @ProductName, @ProductCat
end
```

I call this stored procedure `SPDynamic1` from ASP.NET MVC like this:

```
var query = db.SPDynamic1(para1, para2, para3,...);
```

In here, query returns **int**. How to call the procedure to return result like

```
ProductId ProductName ProductCat
--------------------------------
1         prod001     5
2         prod001     2 
1         prod001     1
```

Comment: Have you `SET NOCOUNT ON` in top of your SP?

Comment: Yes, i have. create procedure SearchProduct(para1,para2,....)as set nocount on ... begin .... end

Comment: Show the code of your SP.

Comment: What are you asking? How to call dynamic SQL or how to get results from your procedure?

Comment: I want to call SP(contain Dynamic Sql) with data input and return data columns in table Product

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up the return value of a procedure (which is always int) and the result set(s)?

Comment: I want to search many criteria with data input from User, i follow this Tut :[link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). But i don't khow how to call this SP with Entity framework.

Comment: Yes, That is my problem. When i execute this SP, return_value is int,result is : data in table Product. How to get  this data ? Sorry, i'm new student.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Entity Framework doesn't support Dynamic Sql.